# SOAP: Migrate method from AXIS 1.4 to CXF for adding a new header

Tags: java, soap, cxf, axis

Hi! I'm trying to add a header to a SOAP call.
I'm new at working with web services.

Every time I need to use the web service for download a file, I need to add a header like:

```xml
<UserIdHeader xmlns="http://www.stats.com/">
    <TicketId>defe3a08-4c8a-47c4-9303-98e09c475532</TicketId>
</UserIdHeader>
```

I'm using CXF. I have one example made with Axis 1.4.
The only thing that is remaining (I hope) is to add this header.

This is what I have to update:

```java
private static void addHeader(String ticketId) {
    SOAPHeaderElement header = new SOAPHeaderElement("http://www.stats.com/", "UserIdHeader");
    SOAPElement node;

    org.apache.axis.client.Stub s = (Stub) service;
    s.clearHeaders();

    try {
        node = header.addChildElement("TicketId");
        node.addTextNode(ticketId);
        s.setHeader((org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement) header);
    } catch (SOAPException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is how I tried to update that:

```java
private static void addHeader(String ticketId) throws JAXBException, ParserConfigurationException {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

    Element eTicketId = doc.createElement("TicketId");
    eTicketId.setTextContent(ticketId);

    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
    Header header = new Header(new QName("http://www.stats.com/", "UserIdHeader"), eTicketId, 
            new JAXBDataBinding(String.class));
    headers.add(header);

    BindingProvider.class.cast(service).getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);
}
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

```java
[PhaseInterceptorChain] Interceptor for {http://www.stats.com/}Service#{http://www.stats.com/}GetFileList has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl is not known to this context
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:261)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.writeSoapEnvelopeStart(SoapOutInterceptor.java:156)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
```

I tried even add an interceptor, but I didn't know how to pass the ticketId.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a DOM element, you shouldn't set a databinding into the Header object.   You only need the Databinding if you are using a JAXB (or other) type.   CXF handles DOM elements directly.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I had to change the method, but your answer was the way. I'll put the working method below.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have the method working (for some reason, with the previous approach the header wasn't written):

```js
private static void addHeader(String ticketId) {
    try {
        SOAPFactory sf = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPElement userIdHeaderElement = sf.createElement(new QName("http://www.stats.com/", "UserIdHeader"));
        SOAPElement ticketIdElement = sf.createElement(new QName(null, "TicketId"));
        ticketIdElement.addTextNode(ticketId);
        userIdHeaderElement.addChildElement(ticketIdElement);
        List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
        Header dummyHeader = new Header(new QName("http://www.stats.com/"), userIdHeaderElement);
        headers.add(dummyHeader);
        BindingProvider.class.cast(service).getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);
    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```